# Bind plugin action for on-the-fly elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've an input field that created on the fly. And I need to bind a plugin interaction from jQueryUI widget.

My code

```
$("select[name='tab_content_length']").live('click', function(){
    $(this).selectmenu({ style: "dropdown"});
});
$("select[name='tab_content_length']").trigger('click');
```

This is crutches and second part won't work. Any ideas how to bind plugin interaction to on-the-fly element?

PS! And I can't and won't bind to 'click', but I don't known any over solutions :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a purpose the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) still serves:

```
$("select[name='tab_content_length']").livequery(function(){
    $(this).selectmenu({ style: "dropdown"});
});
```

Another way would possibly be to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) on a prior event and check if it's been bound...it depends how the plugin is written though, for example `mousedown` happens before `click` (when a user clicks), like this:

```
$("select[name='tab_content_length']").live('mousedown', function(){
  if(!$.data(this, 'menubound')) //prevent re-binding the plugin
    $(this).selectmenu({ style: "dropdown"}).data('menubound', true);
});
```

Comment: I know this is 2 years old but I've been searching for over a month to correct this similar problem I'm having and I found this!